# No data shows with sql in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am connecting to a database with info in it but when i try to access it the app just makes the table and doesn't picking up any of the data. My SQL is a simple "SELECT * FROM 'property'';

```
 <?php 
  if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {; ?>

        <tr class="info">
        <td><?php echo  $row['name'];     ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['monthly'];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['address'];  ?></td>
        <td>
        <td>
            <?php echo '<img src="uploads/'.$row['image'].'" width="360" height="150">'; ?>
        </td>
        <td><a href="single.php?posts=<?php echo  $row['id'];  ?>">Details</a></td>
    </tr>

<?php 
 }
  $result->close;
} ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning any data? What does `echo $result->num_rows;` show?

Comment: because you `close the result`  in the while loop `$result->close;`

Comment: also remove semicolon `;` while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {`;`

Comment: $sql appears to be blank.

Comment: @KUMAR That semicolon won't cause a problem -- it would be a problem if it were before the `{`, but it does nothing after `}`.

Comment: @Barmar ok sir .

Comment: @KUMAR But you're right about `close`. That needs to be one line down, after the end of the loop.